Clarification on Defining Hermitian Structure on Vector Bundles
In Huybrechts's text on complex geometry, he defines a Hermitian structure on a vector bundle $\pi: E \to M$ as Hermitian scalar products on each fiber $E_x$. Specifically, given a trivialization $\psi: E|_U \cong U \times \mathbb{C}^r$ over some open subset $U$ of the base manifold $M$, the Hermitian structure $h$ at $x \in U$ is defined by the form $h_x(\psi^{-1}_x(), \psi^{-1}_x())$, which defines an Hermitian scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^r$.
However, in an example following this definition, Huybrechts defines a Hermitian structure as a map $h: U \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $h(t) = \frac{|\psi(t)|^2}{\sum |\psi(s_i)|^2}$, where $\psi$ is a trivialization and $s_i$ global sections.
My question is: how can we interpret $h(t)$ as defining a Hermitian structure on the vector bundle $E \to M$? Specifically, how can we retrieve the Hermitian (form)-metric from this map $h$?
It would be helpful if the explanation clarified how $h(t)$ is related to the Hermitian scalar product on the fibers $E_x$ and how this map $h$ is consistent with the definition of a Hermitian structure given earlier in the text.

Note that in Example 4.1.2 i), the vector bundle is supposed to be a line bundle.

@red_trumpet I am not sure how I suppose I should use that, it seems you're implying that it has something to do with the dimension, which is one. An extra hint would be nice. For each $x$ each fiber $E_x$ is a 1-dim vector space. So I  need a bilinear map $E_x\times E_x\to \mathbb{C}$ in order to give rise to a inner product. If we pick a local trivil. $$ of $E$ then $v,w\in E_x$ can be spanned from $v=v_1t$, $v_1\in\mathbb{C}$ so we can have something like $<v,w>=v_1\bar{w_1}h(t,t)=v_1\bar{w_1}h(t)$. ...

@red_trumpet The definition does not depend on the chosen trivialization, as
two of them only differ by a scalar factor. But I am still confused about $h$, I can't connect the hole picture nicely.

I guess $h(t) = h(t,t)$ is just the norm? As you noted, for line bundles that is enough to define a hermitian form.
